# using toggleclass on a specific item using id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a button to my site for every item that I have. So basically, I have a list of items and each one of them has a button next to them so that the user can select the wanted item. The problem I am facing is that I can change all of the button's classes when I press one of the buttons but I don't know how to do this depending on the id of the item, this is my toggleclass code so far, when I press a button all buttons become green instead of just one.

```
$(".btn-add").toggleClass("btn-default").toggleClass("btn-success")
```

This is my html code for the button

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-add" onclick='select_item({{item.id}})'>
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-square-o"></i>
</a>
```

Thank you for your time and for your help.

Comment: is the button and the list created dynamically? how about just adding an index to the classes for each item in the list? `.toggleClass("btn-default"+i).toggleClass("btn-success"+i)`

Comment: Yes they are created dynamically, I understand your idea and it might be exactly what I am looking for but how do I add an index to their class in html though? I will edit my question and add the html buttons

Comment: Your missing a `"` in the start of `$(.btn-add")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you are clicking a button with `toggleClass` is that all the other buttons that have that class name will be updated.

A solution that you can do if you still want to use the `toggleClass` function of jquery is to make a unique class name for each button. You can utilize using an index or other variables that may be related to a certain item in your list.

```js
const buttonAdd = `.btn-add-${index}`;
$(buttonAdd).toggleClass("btn-default").toggleClass("btn-success");
```

this way, every button will have a unique class name.

or, it might be better to use `id` for the selector of the button (if you are using the `.btn-add` for some css and stuff)

```js
const buttonAdd = `#btn-add-${index or id}`;
```

then the the button itself should have a functionality of adding an id dynamically:

```html
<a id="{dynamic value here}" class="btn-add ...">... </a>
```

Comment: Yes this would be perfect for what I am doing, the only problem I am facing is how do I add an index or a variable to a html button?

Comment: what language/template/framework are you using for the non-html part of your website?

Comment: I am using python for the backend with flask for routing and plain JS

Comment: if you're using flask, I'm assuming you're using jinja as the html templating engine.. then I think this might be useful for you (the loop/iteration part): https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/

Comment: thanks everybody for your help, it works now :-)